# How swap generic structure in c#?

Tags: c#, struct

I have structure like this below. Now, I want swap 2 structures.

```
public struct Pair<T, U>
{
    public readonly T Fst;
    public readonly U Snd;

    public Pair(T fst, U snd)
    {
        Fst = fst;
        Snd = snd;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "(" + Fst + ", " + Snd + ")";
    }

    **public Pair<U, T> Swap(out Pair<U, T> p1, Pair<T,U> p2)
    {
        p1 = new Pair<U, T>(p2.Snd, p2.Fst);

        return p1; 
    }**
}
```

In Main method try this:

```
        Pair<int, String> t1 = new Pair<int, string>();
        Pair<String, int> t2 = new Pair<string,int>("Anders",13);
        **t1.Swap(out t1,);** //compilator tells -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/dM6P0.png
```

Parameters on Swap method are different than compilator achive.

Comment: Shouldn't you call `t2.Swap` ?

Comment: do you get a compilation error, or is it just the intellisense that is wrong?

Comment: That's really confusing. Using `t1` as an `out` parameter in a method being called on `t1` isn't the kind of code I'd like to pick up.

Comment: @spender That was my thinking exactly - I see no reason for an out parameter here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for out parameters here.  Just define it as:

```
public Pair<U, T> Swap()
{
    return new Pair<U, T>(this.Snd, this.Fst);
}
```

You can then do:

```
Pair<string, int> t2 = new Pair<string,int>("Anders",13);
Pair<int, string> t1 = t2.Swap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Swap` method is a bit confusing. It doesn't make much sense to pass in a parameter by reference (`out`) and then return the same parameter. The parameters the compiler expect are exactly right by the way. You have a `Pair<int,String>` (t1), so T == int and U == String and you have the second argument defined as `Pair<T,U>` so T must be `int` and U must be `String`.

A less confusing implementation of `Swap` would either look like this:

```
public static void Swap(out Pair<U, T> p1, Pair<T,U> p2)
{
    p1 = new Pair<U, T>(p2.Snd, p2.Fst);
}
```

or like this:

```
public void Swap(out Pair<U,T> pSwapped)
{
     pSwapped = new Pair<U,T>(Snd,Fst);
}
```

I would prefer this:

```
public Pair<U,T> Swap()
{
    Pair<U,T> rV = new Pair<U,T>(Snd,Fst);
    return rV;
}
```

however, because there is really no need to pass in anything by reference.